# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object (System.Text.Json)

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, .net-core-3.1

We've got an API, which simply posts incoming JSON documents to a message bus, having assigned a GUID to each.  We're upgrading from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1 and were aiming to replace NewtonSoft with the new `System.Text.Json` library.

We deserialise the incoming document, assign the GUID to one of the fields and then reserialise before sending to the message bus.  Unfortunately, the reserialisation is failing with the exception `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object`.

Here's a controller that shows the problem:-

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/test")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private const string JSONAPIMIMETYPE = "application/vnd.api+json";

        public TestController()
        {
        }

        [HttpPost("{eventType}")]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IActionResult> ProcessEventAsync([FromRoute] string eventType)
        {
            try
            {
                JsonApiMessage payload;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    string payloadString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                    try {
                        payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonApiMessage>(payloadString);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                    }
                }

                if ( ! Request.ContentType.Contains(JSONAPIMIMETYPE) )
                {
                    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
                }

                Guid messageID = Guid.NewGuid();
                payload.Data.Id = messageID.ToString();

                // we would send the message here but for this test, just reserialise it
                string reserialisedPayload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload);

                Request.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = JSONAPIMIMETYPE;
                return Accepted(payload);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JsonApiMessage object is defined like this:-

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class JsonApiMessage
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("data")]
        public JsonApiData Data { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("included")]
        public JsonApiData[] Included { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonApiData
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("attributes")]
        public JsonElement Attributes { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("meta")]
        public JsonElement Meta { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("relationships")]
        public JsonElement Relationships { get; set; }
    }
}
```

An example call looks like this:-

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/test/event
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "data": {
    "type": "test",
    "attributes": {
      "source": "postman",
      "instance": "jg",
      "level": "INFO",
      "message": "If this comes back with an ID, the API is probably working"
    }
  }
}
```

When I examine the contents of `payload` at a breakpoint in Visual Studio, it looks OK at the top level but the `JsonElement` bits look opaque, so I don't know if they've been parsed properly.  Their structure can vary, so we only care that they are valid JSON.  In the old NewtonSoft version, they were `JObject`s.

After the GUID has been added, it appears in the `payload` object when examined at a breakpoint but I'm suspicious that the problem is related to other elements in the object being read-only or something similar.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the post to include a more precise example.

Comment: @JeremyGooch you should post a *minimal* example - string, types and the call to `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonApiMessage>`. I suspect the error has nothing to do with JSON though. You should post the full exception, including the stack trace, not just the message. The stack trace shows where the exception was thrown and the calls that led to it. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Exception Details` in the debugger's exception popup.

Comment: It's reproducible.  Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xzo5Ht

Comment: BTW, why are you using this code in the first place? Why not pass `JsonApiMessage` as an action parameter? You are *bypassing* the streamlined Pipelines and System.Text.Json deserialization this way and lose any benefits. You get *full* allocations by using StreamReader and caching the data into `payloadString`

Comment: @dbc it shouldn't be done this way to begin with though, because it negates any benefit offered by System.Text.Json

Comment: @dbc if you try the code in Linqpad you'll see the *de*serialized object contains `Undefined` Meta and Relationship values, due to the missing attributes.

Comment: @JeremyGooch again, what's the purpose of this code? You're trying to replicate what ASP.NET Core already does in the wrong way. Create a DTO with the shape you want and pass it as a parameter, return it as a value. ASP.NET Core will use System.Text.Json to (de)serialize it with minimal allocations. The *current* code introduces too many bugs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes, that's correct.  I'm writing an answer now explaining the specific problem.  Do you want to address the issue of how it should be done instead, more generally?

Comment: If I remember correctly, we had to use a StreamReader because the MIME type is not "application/json".  It's a vendor MIME type as all of our APIs align to the JSON-API spec.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem can be reproduced with the following more minimal example.  Define the following model:

```
public class JsonApiMessage
{
    public JsonElement data { get; set; }
}
```

Then attempt to deserialize and re-serialize an empty JSON object like so:

```
var payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonApiMessage>("{}");
var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

And you will get an exception (demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oos9yO)):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.WriteTo(Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonConverterJsonElement.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonElement value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

The problem seems to be that [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=netcore-3.1) is a **`struct`**, and the default value for this struct can't be serialized.  In fact, simply doing `JsonSerializer.Serialize(new JsonElement());` throws the same exception (demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qVE1dh)).  (This contrasts with `JObject` which is a reference type whose default value is, of course, `null`.)

So, what are your options?  You could make all your `JsonElement` properties be nullable, and set [`IgnoreNullValues = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorenullvalues?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_IgnoreNullValues) while re-serializing:

```
public class JsonApiData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("attributes")]
    public JsonElement? Attributes { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("meta")]
    public JsonElement? Meta { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("relationships")]
    public JsonElement? Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var reserialisedPayload  = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, new JsonSerializerOptions { IgnoreNullValues = true });
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bsMUyu).

Or, in **.NET 5 or later**, you could mark all of your `JsonElement` properties with [`[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute.condition?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonIgnoreAttribute_Condition):

```
public class JsonApiData
{
    // Remainder unchanged

    [JsonPropertyName("attributes")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public JsonElement Attributes { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("meta")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public JsonElement Meta { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("relationships")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public JsonElement Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

Doing so will cause uninitialized elements to be skipped during serialization without needing to modify serialization options.

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XfjAmi).

Or, you could simplify your data model by binding all the JSON properties other than `Id` to a [`JsonExtensionData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute) property like so:

```
public class JsonApiData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement> ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

This approach avoids the need to manually set `IgnoreNullValues` when re-serializing, and thus ASP.NET Core will re-serialize the model correctly automatically.

Demo fiddle #5 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GvV8I8).

Answer (score 4):

The exception is right - the state of the object is invalid. The `Meta` and `Relasionships` elements are non-nullable but the JSON string doesn't contain them. The *de*serialized object ends up with `Undefined` values in those properties that can't be serialized.

```
    [JsonPropertyName("meta")]
    public JsonElement? Meta { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("relationships")]
    public JsonElement? Relationships { get; set; }
```

The quick fix would be to change those properties to `JsonElement?`. This will allow correct deserialization and serialization. By default, the missing elements will be emitted as nulls:

```
"meta": null,
"relationships": null
```

To ignore them, add the `IgnoreNullValues =true` option :

```
var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, new JsonSerializerOptions 
                           { WriteIndented = true,IgnoreNullValues =true });
```

The *real* solution though would be to get rid of all that code. It *hampers* the use of System.Text.Json. Left by itself, ASP.NET Core uses Pipelines to read the input stream *without* allocating, deserializes the payload and calls the method with the deserialized object as a parameter, using minimal allocations. Any return values are serialized in the same way.

The question's code though allocates a lot - it caches the input in the StreamReader, then the entire payload is cached in the `payloadString` and then again, as the `payload` object. The reverse process also uses temporary strings. This code takes *at least* twice as much RAM as ASP.NET Core would use.

The action code should be just :

```
[HttpPost("{eventType}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessEventAsync([FromRoute] string eventType,
                                                   MyApiData payload)
{
    Guid messageID = Guid.NewGuid();
    payload.Data.Id = messageID.ToString();

    return Accepted(payload);
}
```

Where `MyApiData` is a strongly-typed object. The shape of the Json example corresponds to :

```
public class Attributes
{
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string instance { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
}

public class MyApiData
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public Data[] included {get;set;}
}
```

All other checks are performed by ASP.NET Core itself - ASP.NET Core will reject any `POST` that doesn't have the correct MIME type. It will return a 400 if the request is badly formatted. It will return a 500 if the code throws

Comment: Thanks.  We can't use strongly-typed objects as the lower-level contents of the JSON can vary.  We also had to use a StreamReader because the Content-Type of the incoming payload is `application/vnd.api+json` rather than `application/json` so the declarative deserialisation using the ASP.NET framework doesn't work.  That all said, your solution around handling null values in the incoming JSON and suppressing null elements in the output works well.

Comment: @JeremyGooch you don't have to do those things, or you should do them differently. You can use extendable DTOs by adding dictionaries. You can specify custom formatters in ASP.NET Core configuration (that's how XML is added). If you really need to, you use the Request/Response *pipelines* through the [BodyReader and BodyWriter](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-the-bodyreader-and-bodywriter-in-asp-net-core-3-0) properties

Comment: @JeremyGooch I checked JSON:API and the elements are well defined. A lot of them, but already defined. There's [at least one .NET Core client library](https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore). It doesn't use System.Text.Json, but you can use it as a reference if you want to create your own implementation. By using *formatters* and attributes you avoid littering your actions and controllers with serialization details. At the very least you can borrow the DTO classes.