# Add a pair in JsonDocument

Tags: asp.net-core, system.text.json

I am migrating from *Json.NET - Newtonsoft* to the new *System.Text.Json*. 
In the former source, `JObject` had the `Add` method, however I cannot find a similar function for `JsonElement`.
How would be the way to add a pair to the json object?

Comment: If you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271901/converting-newtonsoft-code-to-system-text-json-in-net-core-3-whats-equivalent/58273914#58273914 it says that you can't edit the JSON data you get from `JsonDocument`.

Comment: `JsonDocument` and `JsonElement` are read-only in .Net 3.1.  As an alternative you could consider deserializing to a partial data model + extension data attribute as shown in [Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object (System.Text.Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59731594/3744182) or [Modifying a JSON file using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001666/3744182).  Beyond those suggestions could you share a [mcve] showing what modification you are trying to make?