# How to add a property to a System.Text.Json.JsonDocument

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I was accustomed to using Newtonsoft's JObject in my Asp.net web api's. I could add properties at will using:

```
            JObject x = new JObject() { "myInt", 25 };
            //or
            x.Add("myInt", 25);
```

I ran into an error when trying to return a JObject from a ASP.Net core 3.1 web app.

```
System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is not supported.
```

So NewtonSoft.Json is not supported in .Net core 3.1. So I looked at this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to but it seems that you can not add a property to a JsonDocument. This seems very odd and I thought I might be missing some information. So is there a way to add a property and value to a JsonDocument?

Comment: You can still add `NewtonSoft.Json` to ASP.NET Core 3 and use it instead of default `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Are you really sure that first code block will work with Newtonsoft? I'm pretty sure it will still throw an exception.

Comment: ```JObject x = new JObject();
x["myInt"] = "25";```

Comment: @DavidG i It works and makes JObject very flexible.

Comment: @cerberus I want to add a property to JsonDocument not JObject?

Comment: But even your exception shown here is a Newtonsoft exception, doesn't that prove it doesn't work?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski seems odd no way to add a property tho.

Comment: @DavidG Newtonsoft doesn't work with .net core 3 so I need to work with JsonDocument which does - I just wanted to add some properties to a response but apparently not possibe.

Comment: I've just tried it in a .NET Framework 4.8 app with Newtonsoft and it throws an exception.

Comment: @DavidG Your right I was returning JObject .ToString(). However seems strange you don't have the flexibility to add a property to a with JsonDocument.

Comment: Why do you even want to add things to a JsonDocument anyway? Just work in a `Dictionary` or whatever and serialise when you need to.

Comment: *So is there a way to add a property and value to a JsonDocument?* - no, there isn't, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001666/3744182) and [Writable Json DOM #39922](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39922)

Comment: But sometimes there are alternatives, see e.g. [Modifying a JSON file using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58997718/3744182) or [Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object (System.Text.Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59719751/3744182).  Or you could construct an anonymous object or dictionary.  Can you share some details about what you are actually doing?  There's no real need to use `JObject` in the simple case shown.