# Equivalent of JObject in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-5, system.text.json

I have DTO class that has a property of type `JObject`. This DTO class is send/receive over HTTP between multiple services. JObject is used because the `ExtractedData` does not have predefined properties

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public JObject ExtractedData {get;set;}
}
```

I am converting this project to .NET 5. What is equivalent to JObject in .NET 5? I am trying to avoid JsonDocument because (from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#jsondocument-is-idisposable)):

> JsonDocument builds an in-memory view of the data into a pooled
> buffer. Therefore, unlike JObject or JArray from Newtonsoft.Json, the
> JsonDocument type implements IDisposable and needs to be used inside a
> using block.

I am planing to use `JsonElement`.  Is this the most appropriate choice or is there any other type available to hold JSON as an object?

Answer (score 105):

As of Nov 2021, `.NET 6` introduces the [System.Text.Json.Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes?view=net-6.0) namespace which:

> Provides types for handling an in-memory writeable document object
> model (DOM) for random access of the JSON elements within a structured
> view of the data

The four new types are `JsonArray`, `JsonObject`, `JsonNode` and `JsonValue`.
The closest type to `JObject` is [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject?view=net-6.0) which offers similar functionality.

See below for some examples:

```
// create object manually using initializer syntax
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject
{
    ["Id"] = 3,
    ["Name"] = "Bob",
    ["DOB"] = new DateTime(2001, 02, 03),
    ["Friends"] = new JsonArray
    {
        new JsonObject 
        {
            ["Id"] = 2,
            ["Name"] = "Smith"
        },
        new JsonObject
        {
            ["Id"] = 4,
            ["Name"] = "Jones"
        } 
    }
};

// random access to values
int id = (int)obj["Id"];
DateTime dob = (DateTime)obj["DOB"];
string firstFriendName = (string)obj["Friends"][0]["Name"];
```

Some other cool things which now make using `System.Text.Json` much easier in `.NET6` are listed below.

**Parse, Create, and DOM Manipulation**

```
// parse
var jsonObj = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString).AsObject();
```

If you have a `JsonElement` (perhaps after deserializing into `dynamic`, `object`, or `JsonElement`) you can call `Create`, now you have a navigable and writable DOM object:

```
// create
JsonObject obj = JsonObject.Create(jsonElement);
```

You can Add/Remove properties:

```
obj.Add("FullName", "Bob Smith");
bool successfullyRemoved = obj.Remove("Name");
```

Safely interrogate object for particular key using `ContainsKey` and `TryGetPropertyValue` (which returns a `JsonNode`):

```
if (obj.ContainsKey("Hobbies"))
    // do stuff

if (obj.TryGetPropertyValue("Hobbies", out JsonNode? node))
    // do stuff with node
```

**Project and Filter data**

It's possible to use Linq to project and filter the `JsonObject`:

```
// select Keys
List<string> keys = obj.Select(node => node.Key).ToList();
// filter friends
var friends = obj["Friends"].AsArray()
             .Where(n => (int)n.AsObject()["Id"] > 2);
```

**Deserialize Json**

It's now easy to deserialize the Json or deserialize a portion of the Json.  This is useful when we only want to deserialize partial Json from the main object.  For the example above we can deserialize the list of friends into a generic `List<Friend>` easily:

```
List<Friend> friends = obj["Friends"].AsArray().Deserialize<List<Friend>>();
```

where `Deserilize<T>()` is an extension method on `JsonNode`.

**Serialize**

It's easy to serialize the `JsonObject` by using `ToJsonString()`:

```
string s = obj.ToJsonString();

// write pretty json with WriteIndented
string s = obj.ToJsonString(new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
```

---

In your particular case you could define `JsonObject` in your DTO:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public JsonObject ExtractedData {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 27):

In **.NET 5** and **.NET Core 3.1** the closest equivalent to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) is indeed [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement) so you could modify your DTO as follows:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public JsonElement ExtractedData {get;set;}
}
```

There is no need to worry about disposing of any documents as, internally, the [`JsonElementConverter`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.0/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/JsonElementConverter.cs) used by [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer) returns a non-pooled element (by cloning the element in .NET 5).

However, the correspondence is not exact, so keep the following in mind:

1. `JsonElement` represents any JSON value and thus corresponds most closely to [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) not `JObject`.  As `JsonElement` is a `struct` there is no subclass corresponding to a JSON object.  If you want to constrain `ExtractedData` to be a JSON object you will need to check this in the setter:

   ```
   public class MyDTO
   {
       JsonElement extractedData;

       public JsonElement ExtractedData
       {
           get => extractedData;
           set
           {
               if (value.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Object
                   // && value.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Null Uncomment if you want to allow null
                   )
                   throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a JSON object type", value.ValueKind));
               extractedData = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Since `JsonElement` is a struct, the default value is not `null`.  So, what is it?  It turns out that `default(JsonElement)` has [`ValueKind = JsonValueKind.Undefined`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonvaluekind?view=net-5.0):

   > There is no value (as distinct from Null).

   If you attempt to serialize such a default `JsonElement` with `JsonSerializer`, an exception will be thrown.  I.e. if you simply do

   ```
   var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyDTO());
   ```

   Then a `System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.` exception is thrown.

   You have a few options to avoid this problem:

   - In .NET 5 you can apply [`[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute.condition?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonIgnoreAttribute_Condition) like so:

     ```
     public class MyDTO
     {
         [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
         public JsonElement ExtractedData {get;set;}
     }
     ```

     This causes uninitialized values of `ExtractedData` to be skipped during serialization.
   - In .NET Core 3.x `JsonIgnoreCondition` does not exist, so you could instead define `ExtractedData` to be nullable:

     ```
     public class MyDTO
     {
         public JsonElement? ExtractedData {get;set;}
     }
     ```

     Or you could initialize it to a null `JsonElement` like so:

     ```
     public class MyDTO
     {
         public JsonElement ExtractedData {get;set;} = JsonExtensions.Null;
     }

     public static class JsonExtensions
     {
         static readonly JsonElement nullElement = CreateNull();

         public static JsonElement Null => nullElement;

         static JsonElement CreateNull()
         {
             using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse("null");
             return doc.RootElement.Clone();
         }
     }
     ```

     Both options cause uninitialized values of `ExtractedData` to serialize as `null`.
3. See also the related questions:

   - *[Converting newtonsoft code to System.Text.Json in .net core 3. what's equivalent of JObject.Parse and JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58271901/3744182)*.
   - *[Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object (System.Text.Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59719751/3744182)*.