# Deserialize Json input to dynamic

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I want to deserialize a Json document without knowing anything about its content (can't use a strongly typed .NET class).

I was using the following code with Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize to dynamic:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJsonInput);
```

What would be the equivalent with System.Text.Json?

To add more context, the json document is an array of objects and I'm using dynamic to be able to add an extra property to each object in the document before building a List. Example below:

```
var strInput = @"[
            {
                ""email"": ""hello@toto.com"",
                ""event"": ""processed""
            },
            {
                ""email"": ""hello@toto.com"",
                ""event"": ""deferred"",
                ""category"": ""cat facts""
            }]";

dynamic rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strInput);

List<dynamic> outputList = new List<dynamic>();

foreach (var item in rawData)
{
    item.id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    outputList.Add(item);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: System.Text.Json does not support deserializing to `dynamic`.  And in any event using `dynamic` sets you up for problems down the road as you lose all compile-time checking for correctness; see [Is the use of dynamic considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31859016) for more. The best alternative would be to deserialize to `JsonNode`, see [Equivalent of JObject in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71018559).  (When using Json.NET a `dynamic` object is actually a `JObject`.)

Comment: For instance, here's the equivalent of your code using the `System.Text.Json.Nodes` namespace: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jzRbrN.  Note I deserialized to a `List<JsonObject>` because your code assumes that the incoming JSON has that shape.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Crystal clear. Thanks a lot for your detailed comments and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm), System.Text.Json [does not implement](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66638) deserializing to `dynamic` with automatic mapping of JSON property names to dynamic .NET property names. Instead of `dynamic`, you can deserialize free-form JSON to a [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode) or one of its subtypes from the [`System.Text.Json.Nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom#json-dom-choices) namespace introduced in .NET 7.

Using this API, your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonObject>>(strInput)!;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item["id"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jzRbrN)

Notes:

- Your question states that you don't know "anything" about the JSON, but your code in fact assumes that the root JSON container is an array of objects.  Because of that, I deserialized to a `List<JsonObject>`.

  If you truly are uncertain whether the root JSON container is actually an array, you can parse to a `JsonNode` and check like so:

  ```
  var rawJson = JsonNode.Parse(strInput);
  if (rawJson is JsonArray array)
  {
      foreach (var item in array.OfType<JsonObject>())
      {
          item["id"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      }
  }
  ```

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tR7h9V).
- In general I don't recommend using `dynamic` when parsing free-form JSON for all the reasons mentioned in *[Is the use of dynamic considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31859016)*.  You may think you are writing code which is independent of the serializer used when parsing to `dynamic`, but actually your Json.NET code only works because NewtonSoft implemented `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` for all its `JToken` types.

  But if you **must** deserialize to `dynamic` with System.Text.Json (e.g. to interact with legacy code that cannot be rewritten), since there is nothing built-in you will need to deserialize to something like `ExpandoObject`.  `ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974452/3744182) to *[C# - Deserializing nested json to nested Dictionary<string, object>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65972825/3744182)* can be used for this purpose:

  ```
  var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
  {
      // ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter copied from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65974452/3744182
      // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972825/c-sharp-deserializing-nested-json-to-nested-dictionarystring-object/
      Converters = { new ObjectAsPrimitiveConverter(floatFormat : FloatFormat.Double, unknownNumberFormat : UnknownNumberFormat.Error, objectFormat : ObjectFormat.Expando) },
      // Add other options as required, e.g.:
      WriteIndented = true,
  };

  var rawData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<dynamic>>(strInput, options)!;

  var outputList = new List<dynamic>();

  foreach (var item in rawData)
  {
      item.id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

      outputList.Add(item);
  }
  ```

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FZ86UD).